# Can we find $V_n$ in such a way that $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$ is countable?

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

> If $V_n$ is open, dense subset of $\mathbb R$ for each $n\in \mathbb N$ then by Baire's Category theorem we know that $\displaystyle \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.
>
> My question is that : Can we find $V_n$ in such a way that     $\displaystyle \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$ is countable set?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we cannot. Suppose otherwise. Then $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}V_n=\{r_1,r_2,r_3,\ldots\}$. Now, let $W_n=V_n\setminus\{r_n\}$. Then $W_n$ is also an open dense subset of $\mathbb R$. But now $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}W_n=\emptyset$, which is impossible, by Baire's theorem.

Comment: We could also take $W_n=V_n \setminus \{r_n\}$.

Comment: @nurunnesha You are right. That's even simpler. Do you mind if I edit my answer so that it uses your idea?

Comment: Yeah, sure edit your answer.

Answer (score 3):

No.  If $S = \int_{n=1}^\infty V_n$ were countable, you could make it empty by intersecting with another countable sequence of dense open sets (the complements of each member of $S$), and thereby violate Baire.